# Django model field name suggestions (autocomplete) in VSC

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have in VSC help text during creation of object? Example:

```
class Fruit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

and now somewhere else in code:

```
Fruit.objects.create(>>> dropdown suggestions of possible field names of Fruit model here fe. 'name')
```

Comment: write an extension that parses your python files, extracts `models.Model` sub classes, collect all the fields, write a `CompletionItemProvider` that detects a `XYZ.objects.create` and supply suggestions, it is more than an hours work, be aware to be able to parse the `create` arguments to be able to suggest a second argument

Comment: PyCharm professional (paid) has Django support for this, but most code interpreters will not be able to do this, because it uses a lot of meta-programming to define fields and lookups, and code interpreters can not "understand" this (at least not with the current level of interpretation) no.

Answer (score 1):

I just developed a VSCode extension that does exactly that: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mordor1110.djanto

It's in an early stage so feel free to make suggestions or request features. Have in mind that it doesn't use any language server, it just parses the files where your models are at to find their attributes. I know it's not very "fancy", but it works! :)